# Data fetch although I'm not clicking the button yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

right now I'm learning react. I still new about this. So, I make a little code here.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Search = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [countryFromButtonClick, setCountryFromButtonClick] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries/${countryFromButtonClick}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setData(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(err.response.data.message);
      });
  }, [countryFromButtonClick]);

  const HandleChange = e => {
    setCountry(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCountryFromButtonClick(country);
  };

  return (
    <section id="search-country">
      <h1> Number of Cases </h1>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="input-group mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Search Country..."
            value={country}
            onChange={HandleChange}
          />
          <div className="input-group-append">
            <button
              className="btn btn-outline-secondary"
              type="button"
              id="button-addon2"
              onClick={handleClick}
            >
              Search
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h1>
          {data.country} {data.cases}
        </h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

The problem is, I'm not clicking the search button yet, but It's already fetch the data.
The console showing error from `console.log(err)`.
Is there anything I can do, So the data only fetch when I click the button?

Thanks.

Comment: `useEffect` calls the callback once on initial render, *then* when the deps change. Have you tried adding e.g. `if (countryFromButtonClick)` in there?

Answer (score 0):

What's up?

So, when you use `useEffect` hook and put any variable inside of the array, the code is executed, because of the value changed, so, if you want to fetch this, I recommend to create a function with the code that is inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: As a note, you can also just put the data call directly in the handleClick() function and it would work fine. You'd then be able to remove the countryFromButtonClick state and the useEffect.